# How do I track when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, point

On my website, I want to track AD clicks and reward users. Basically a PayPerClick. When the user clicks the AD or Link, I want to increment the amount of points they have. Is there a simple way to do this?

I'm guessing i will have to use javascript for this.

dbeas.com

Comment: You need some kind of server code to store your clicks. Javascript is not neccessarly needed.

Comment: These links should give you a clue: http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/php/scripts-programs/click-tracking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will get you started.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/w0q61g0e/1/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
var points = 0;

$("a.ad").click(function() {
  points++;
  //send point to server
  //tell the user about the increase in points
  alert(points);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='ad' target='_blank' href='http://www.google.com'> This is Ad</a>
<br>
<a target='_blank' href='http://www.google.com'> This is Not an Ad</a>
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you! Isn't this jQuery? I remember jQuery having "$" at the beginning.

Comment: Happy to help:) . And yes, it is [**`jQuery`**](http://jquery.com/).